# Flask-Login Issue: current_user is still of type AnonymousUserMixin after Authentication and Redirect

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a login page that uses a custom FlaskForm (using WTForms). If a user enters the correct credentials, a PostgreSQL database is successfully queried (using flask-sqlalchemy) to see if a user with that name and (hashed) password exists. If there is such a user, login_user(user) is ran, and redirection to the homepage of my site is attempted.

I have implemented flask-login (as per the online documentation), but when a user provides valid credentials for logging in, they are redirected back to the login page (as if they had not provided valid credentials). I am using Google Chrome.

I have determined that after redirecting to the homepage, the current_user is of type AnonymousUserMixin (even though current user in the login function is of type User (which I have defined, inheriting all methods from UserMixin).

Here's what I have tried:

- Ensured my code meets the specifications outlined in the Flask documentation
- Browsed articles on StackOverflow, Reddit, and various blogs. From those, I have made the following changes to my code:
- Inserted the hidden_tag() and csrf_token() fields into my login form (see the final code excerpt)
- Added a secret key to my Flask application
- Encoded and decoded (with utf8) the id of the current user (see below code, also in the User class definition further below)

  return str(self.id).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')

As per the [flask-login documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I have put the following into my file application.py (the file where my flask code is):

At the top of the file:

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
```

A user loader function:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=:id", {"id": id})
    return User.get(current_user, id)
```

A user class (which inherits UserMixin):

```
class User(UserMixin):
    is_active = True
    is_anonymous = False
    def __init__(self, email, name, id, input_password_hash):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password_hash = input_password_hash

    def check_password(self, password, password_hash_byte_literal):
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), password_hash_byte_literal)

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')

    def get(self, user_id):
        id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", {"user_id": user_id})
        if id:
            name = db.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", {"user_id": user_id})
            email = db.execute("SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", {"user_id": user_id})
            password_hash = db.execute("SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", {"user_id": user_id})
            user_name_string = ''
            user_email_string = ''
            user_password_hash_string = ''
            for row in name:
                for i in range(len(row)):
                    user_name_string += row[i]
            for row in email:
                for i in range(len(row)):
                    user_email_string += row[i]
            for row in password_hash:
                for i in range(len(row)):
                    user_password_hash_string += row[i]
            return User(user_email_string, user_name_string, user_id, user_password_hash_string)
        else:
            return None
```

Below is my login route:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
        user_pw_hash = (db.execute("SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE email=:email", {"email": email}).fetchone())
        user_id = (db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=:email", {"email": email}).fetchone())
        if user_id:
            password_hash_string = ''
            id_string = str(user_id)
            for row in user_pw_hash:
                for i in range(len(row)):
                    password_hash_string += row[i]
            user_id_int = int(id_string[1])
            user = User.get(user, user_id_int)
            password_hash_byte_literal = bytes(password_hash_string, encoding='utf8')
            correct_password = User.check_password(user, password, password_hash_byte_literal)
            if correct_password:
                login_user(user)
                next = url_for("index")
                if not is_safe_url(next, {"http://127.0.0.1:5000"}):
                    return abort(400)
                return redirect(next or url_for("login"))
            else:
                return render_template("login.html", message="Incorrect username or password.", form=form)
        else:
            return render_template("login.html", message="No account with that email address was found.", form=form)

    else:
        return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

As per the flask-login documentation, I login the user with the login_user function (see above), and I check to see if the next url (my homepage -- "index") is safe. If it is, I proceed to redirect the user to that page.

Also, below is my login form (which includes the hidden_tag() and csrf_token() fields).

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button><br>
</form>
```

I realize that this code does not yet properly sanitize inputs before executing PostgreSQL commands. I will work on fixing this issue very soon.

Imports:

```
import os
from flask import flash, Flask, session, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_session import Session
from is_safe_url import is_safe_url
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm, ReviewForm   # Custom WTForms I wrote
import bcrypt
```

[Command Line Output when User Submits Form and Redirected to Homepage is Attempted (index)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3S4X.jpg)

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020 18:42:35] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020 18:42:48] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020 18:42:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020 18:42:48] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I am using Visual Studio code (and its PowerShell) to run and edit this Flask application.

Versions:

```
Windows 10
Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
bcrypt 3.1.7
email-validator 1.1.1
Python 3.8.2
Flask 1.1.2
Flask-WTF 0.14.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.3
Flask-Session 0.3.2
Flask-Login 0.5.0
Flask-Bootstrap
WTForms 2.3.1
SQLAlchemy 1.3.16
mysql-connector-python 8.0.19
mysql-client 0.0.1
Jinja2 2.11.2
itsdangerous 1.1.0
is-safe-url 1.0
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

#### Update

Below is my updated code (with changes made based on others' insightful comments):

Login Function:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
        user_id = (db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=:email", {"email": email}).fetchone())
        if user_id:
            user_pw_hash = (db.execute("SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE email=:email", {"email": email}).fetchone())
            password_hash_string = user_pw_hash.password_hash
            user = User(None, None, None, False)
            user_id_int = user_id.id
            user = load_user(user_id_int)
            password_hash_byte_literal = bytes(password_hash_string, encoding='utf8')
            correct_password = User.check_password(user, password, password_hash_byte_literal)
            if correct_password:
                login_user(user)
                next = url_for("index")
                if not is_safe_url(next, {"http://127.0.0.1:5000"}):
                    return abort(400)
                else:
                    return redirect(next or url_for("login"))
            else:
                return render_template("login.html", message="Incorrect email or password.", form=form)
        else:
            return render_template("login.html", message="No account with that email address was found.", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

Login Manager User Loader:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    user_data = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id", {"id": id}).fetchone()
    if user_data:
        return User(user_data.email, user_data.name, id, user_data.password_hash)
    else:
        return None
```

A Get ID function from my User class:

```
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
```

The above two function work correctly, but users are still redirected to the login page after attempting to sign in with valid credentials.

Again, thank you all for your help; it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: With problems like these I find that it’s easiest to write a test that is failing, hook a debugger up to it and pick at it. Not to say you aren’t doing this, but the debugger is key.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for the suggestion. How do you recommend testing the software (i.e. what packages, software, etc. should I use)?

Comment: I personally use Pycharm and its debugger. I would run the flask site in `DEBUG` mode. Make the request in the actual site with dev tools open, see what is actually being sent. Create a test using flasks test client (google it, it’s about 5 lines of code) sending that same data. Then using that start making changes rerunning the test each time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for the suggestion. I’ll work on doing what you said and will let you know what I find.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as you, when I don't set the remember=True, I can not redirect after using **flask.login_user**

Per flask-login docs: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_user
remember (bool) – Whether to remember the user after their session expires. Defaults to **False.**

so I think I have some configuration that my session expires right after my initial request, because if I set remember to **True**

so instead of doing:

```
login_user(user)
```

try

```
login_user(user=user, remember=True)
```

## Suggestion 2:

my guess would be to take a double look into your function to get the user from the database *def get(self, user_id):*, make sure this is returning the user object properly and not None.
Also the login_user() from flask.login should return True if the login is successful.
This how I would find and get the user from the db using id:

```
def find_user_by_id(user_id: int):
row = db.execute('select * from users u where u.id =:user_id',
                 {'user_id': user_id}).fetchone()
if row is None:
    return None
else:
    return User(user_id=row.id, first_name=row.first_name,
                last_name=row.last_name, email=row.email, reviews=None, password_hash=row.password)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried passing in remember=True as an argument to the login_user function, but the user could still not login. I will let you know if I figure out how to fix the issue I am having.

Comment: André, I ensured that my get function correctly retrieves values from the database and that login_user(user) (where user is a user created using the get function) returns True. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're not implementing the `flask-login` requirements correctly. Try using the default `user_loader` callback and seeing if it fixes your issue.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    # Whichever method you use to load a user, it needs to be guaranteed unique
    field_values = list(db.execute("SELECT id, name, email, password_hash FROM users WHERE id=:id", {"id": id}))
    
    return User(**dict(field_values))
```

and in your `User` model

```
def get_id(self):
    # this matches what user_loader needs to uniquely load a user
    return self.id
```

See: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works

Comment: Hello, I have a quick question: can User.query.get() be used without inheriting from db.Model in my User class? I apologize, I forgot to clarify that I am trying to not inherit from db.Model for this app (so as to practice writing the actual SQL queries in Postgres).

Comment: Also, I wrote a different get method that correctly returns a user from the database with their information. Unfortunately, I am still redirected back to the login page after attempting to login with valid credentials.

Comment: Either way, your `user_loader` needs to match your `User` model's `get_id()` no matter how you choose to load the user. The way you're passing in `current_user` and trying to use `get()` as a static method on the `User` class is another issue. I'll update the answer to possibly fit the way you want to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested implementation! I have implemented get_id as you have above, and have implemented load_user so that it correctly returns a user object with the appropriate data. Alas, I am still redirected back to the login page upon attempting to sign in.

Comment: Also, I no longer pass in current_user and I no longer use get() as a static method.

Comment: Working on it now.